# Finding the certificate store name in my virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to add a SSL certificate secret to my Linux virtual machine in Azure. I am following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvmsecret?view=azps-3.6.1

Now, according to the documentation, I need to perform this command from powershell:

```
Add-AzVMSecret -VM $VirtualMachine -SourceVaultId $SourceVaultId -CertificateStore $CertificateStore01 -CertificateUrl $CertificateUrl01
```

I have the following information:

- $VirtualMachine
- $SourceVaultId
- $CertificateUrl01

However, I don't know the *$CertificateStore01*, which according to the documentation is the the 'name of a certificate store on the virtual machine.' I haven't been able to find this from my virtual machine, does anyone know how to get it?

I tried doing this as well:

```
$certURL=(Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $key).id
$vm=Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vmName
$vaultId=(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VaultName $keyVaultName).ResourceId
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore "/etc/ssl/certs" -CertificateUrl $certURL

Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
```

but ended up with this error:

```
Update-AzVM: Parameter 'certificateStore' is not allowed.
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
ErrorMessage: Parameter 'certificateStore' is not allowed.
ErrorTarget: certificateStore
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: According to the official doc, Certificate Store parameter is only required for Windows VMs:

> Specifies the name of a certificate store on the virtual machine that
>   runs the Windows operating system. This cmdlet adds the certificate to
>   the store that this parameter specifies. You can only specify this
>   parameter for virtual machines that run the Windows operating system.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvmsecret?view=azps-3.6.1#parameters

Comment: I see all of my certificates stored there. However, I was wondering what is my CertificateStore name? edited my question title for clarity

Comment: I believe this is applicable for windows only

Comment: so for Linux I can just skip that argument?

Comment: it must start with `/` so the right value should be /etc/ssl/certs

Comment: Tried it with /etc/ssl/certs and also without that -CertificateStore altogether. I still get the same error: Update-AzVM: Parameter 'certificateStore' is not allowed.